# Move joins from Where clause to From clause in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have the follwing Oracle query and I want to move the joins from the *Where* clause to the *From* clause

```
select 
    * 
from
    A, B, C
where
    A.a (+)= B.a
    AND A.b (+) = B.b
    AND A.b = C.b;
```

So I came up with the following query

```
select
    *
from
    C,
    B left join A on (B.a = A.a and B.b = A.b and C.b = A.b);
```

I want to know if the two queries are semantically the same and if both will output the same results

*** Edit: Attempt 2

```
select
    *
from    
    B left join A on (B.a = A.a and B.b = A.b)
    inner join C on C.b = A.b;
```

Comment: Don't mix modern explicit JOIN and old, comma separated ones. Switch to explicit JOIN's everywhere.

Comment: That query is actually invalid, since the ON clause should be evaluated before the comma separated C is found.

Comment: @jarlh I have just edited my question. Maybe the second attempt is equivalent to the original query ?

Comment: Attempt 2 is equivalent to your first query

Comment: I agree that attempt 2 is equivalent to your first query. This is the proper transformation from old to new syntax. The two queries are hence even similar in the aspect that both make it look like you are outer-joining table A when you are actually inner-joining it. (For the same column order it would have to be `select a.*, b.*, c.* ...` instead of `select *`, though, but that's a minor detail.)

Comment: By the way, there are no brackets around an `on` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old Oracle join syntax the `(+)` is to be applied to all columns of the outer-joined table. In your original query it is hence table A that gets outer-joined to table B, because

```
FROM a, b
WHERE a.a (+) = b.a AND a.b (+) = b.b
```

is

```
FROM b
LEFT join a ON a.a = b.a AND a.b = b.b
```

But `AND a.b = c.b` in your query renders this a mere inner join, because it would have to be `AND a.b (+) = c.b` for a working outer join (in which case you would probably want `a.b = c.b`, too, in order not to cross join the two tables).

So your query boils down to:

```
select * 
from a
inner join b on b.a = a.a and b.b = a.b
inner join c on c.b = a.b;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the following is your working query then I must say it is not doing what is expected.

```
select 
    * 
from
    A, B, C
where
    A.a (+)= B.a -- b left join a
    AND A.b (+) = B.b -- b left join a
    AND A.b = C.b; -- c inner join a
```

It is nothing but the inner join of all three tables as the last condition made it inner join between a and c. it will return data only if there is data available both in a and c (and offcourse b). (inner join)

To get the exact result, you simply need an inner join.

```
SELECT * FROM
B INNER JOIN A ON A.A=B.A AND A.B = B.B
INNER JOIN C ON A.B = C.B
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably intend this query as:

```
select * 
from B left join
     A
     using (a, b) left join
     C
     using (b)
```